# Fix of a navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slice

Please see the colored navigation bar here:
http://profsyntax.com/test/7Days/

when I zoom in/out the navigation bar is getting spoiled. How can I fix this?

Comment: In what way is it 'getting spoiled'?

Comment: You're using a [background-image](http://profsyntax.com/test/7Days/graphics/elements/navBG.png) on the entire nav and guessing the width of your nav items, that's why. You should use background colors on the individual items instead.

Comment: Text (News Busines Metrolife) moves out of the colors.

Comment: @Masmartigan I have used background-image as I should have shadow and rounded boarders without using CSS3 :(

Comment: Your desire for strict CSS2 is unrelated to your zoom problem. You can't accurately guess widths based on font size, which can change on different devices, different OS, or different conditions (like zooming or user preferences). I've voted to close as "too localized" because the only demo of your issue is on a live site and there's no code or screenshot here. The moment you start editing the site, your post's value drops to zero because the problem is gone or not what it originally was.

Comment: @Madmartigan dear Madmartigan you are fully right! This is not a good question. But seems that you can hint me the principle of solving my problem. Could you please tell it?

Comment: If you can edit this question into something useful (i.e. not just a link to your live website) I will post a solution or two.

Comment: GL, someone else may be able to help - I have to leave for the day now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used absolute placement and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use background image, then it will get spoiled when zooming.

If you want to use Css3 shadow and rounded borders , just use Mordernizr script here, it supports most important CSS 3 features in old browser and it's quite amazing:

http://www.modernizr.com/